# "Dynamics CRM Destination" does not have a value for the ID property

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dynamics-crm, data-migration

While using the KingwaySoft tool for data migration from Dynamics CRM to another CRM table, I encountered an error message stating: 'The 'Dynamics CRM Destination.Connections[DynamicsCRM]' in the connection manager collection, Connections, of 'Dynamics CRM Destination' does not have a value for the ID property. I have ensured that the ConnectionManagerID property of the runtime connection object has been set for the component.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEjh6.png)

Want to know why this error is coming and  step to resolve this error

Comment: I've used the Kingswaysoft connector a lot for Dynamics CRM.  I think you need to remove the ID column from the destination as CRM will auto-populate it.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I tried this but it is not working, The problem is that there is no save button on the Dynamics CRM Destination button

Comment: From memory, you need to go into the Advanced Properties of the Destination object, and remove the fields there